# How to reference a nested dictionary in Python and don't know how, please someone give an explanation

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested, urllib

So I'm using a decent size API to create a discord bot. I am having some trouble getting the information I need out of the API because of the nested dictionary. I took the api, and made it into a json, and am using that as my dictionary. I can call the status just fine, because it's at the top of the tree, but I am completely lost when it comes to going down the tree. Please help!

Here's my code:

```py
import urllib

from urllib.request import urlopen as open

import json


url = 'https://fortnite-api.com/v2/shop/br/combined'

#opens url

json_obj = open(url)

#saves to json

json_data = json.load(json_obj)

#prints URL

print(url)

###variables for dictionary's

json_status = json_data['status']


#prints API Status, 200 is connected

print('API Status: ' + str(json_status))    



#Going down the tree, am lost

json_names = json_data['data']['featured']['entries']['items']['name']

print(json_names)
```

The json tree is in this link, under "BR Shop Combined". Just click on the Responses. It is too complicated to type out. https://dash.fortnite-api.com/

Here's the json:
{"status":200,"data":{"hash":"aefe4148418f3406bfd155349369360c70e13534","date":"2020-07-10T00:00:00Z","featured":{"name":"Featured","entries":
[{"regularPrice":2000,"finalPrice":2000,"bundle":null,"banner":{"value":"Selectable Styles!","backendValue":"SelectableStyles"},"giftable":true,"refundable":true,"sortPriority":-11,"categories":["Panel 3"],"devName":"[VIRTUAL]1 x Moisty Merman, 1 x Mertank for 2000 MtxCurrency","offerId":"v2:/ecbc2dd0399e9510014273e231bf6b1ae6cd0caeb3d1da754a0715a55615f6e3","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_CID_130_Athena_Commando_M_Merman","items":[{"id":"CID_130_Athena_Commando_M_Merman","name":"Moisty Merman","description":"From the moisty depths of... the backlot of Studio B.","type":{"value":"outfit","displayValue":"Outfit","backendValue":"AthenaCharacter"},"rarity":{"value":"legendary","displayValue":"Legendary","backendValue":"EFortRarity::Legendary"},"series":null,"set":null,"introduction":{"chapter":"1","season":"4","text":"Introduced in Chapter 1, Season 4.","backendValue":4},"images":{"smallIcon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_130_athena_commando_m_merman/smallicon.png","icon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_130_athena_commando_m_merman/icon.png","featured":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_130_athena_commando_m_merman/featured.png","other":null},"variants":[{"channel":"Material","type":"COLOR","options":[{"tag":"Mat1","name":"DEFAULT","image":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_130_athena_commando_m_merman/variants/material/mat1.png"},{"tag":"Mat2","name":"BLUE","image":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_130_athena_commando_m_merman/variants/material/mat2.png"},{"tag":"Mat3","name":"ORANGE","image":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_130_athena_commando_m_merman/variants/material/mat3.png"},{"tag":"Mat4","name":"PURPLE","image":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_130_athena_commando_m_merman/variants/material/mat4.png"}]}],"gameplayTags":["Cosmetics.Source.ItemShop","Cosmetics.UserFacingFlags.HasVariants","Cosmetics.Filter.Season.4"],"showcaseVideo":"TGD91vW8vnw","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_CID_130_Athena_Commando_M_Merman","definitionPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Heroes/HID_130_Athena_Commando_M_Merman","path":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Cosmetics/Characters/CID_130_Athena_Commando_M_Merman","added":"2019-11-20T12:50:24Z","shopHistory":["2018-05-25T00:00:00Z","2018-05-26T00:00:00Z","2018-06-28T00:00:00Z","2018-07-31T00:00:00Z","2018-09-04T00:00:00Z","2018-12-05T00:00:00Z","2019-09-13T00:00:00Z","2019-09-14T00:00:00Z","2019-10-16T00:00:00Z","2019-11-25T00:00:00Z","2020-02-04T00:00:00Z","2020-03-23T00:00:00Z","2020-04-28T00:00:00Z","2020-06-05T00:00:00Z","2020-07-10T00:00:00Z"]},{"id":"BID_051_Merman","name":"Mertank","description":"Breathe easy.","type":{"value":"backpack","displayValue":"Back Bling","backendValue":"AthenaBackpack"},"rarity":{"value":"legendary","displayValue":"Legendary","backendValue":"EFortRarity::Legendary"},"series":null,"set":null,"introduction":{"chapter":"1","season":"4","text":"Introduced in Chapter 1, Season 4.","backendValue":4},"images":{"smallIcon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/bid_051_merman/smallicon.png","icon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/bid_051_merman/icon.png","featured":null,"other":null},"variants":null,"gameplayTags":["Cosmetics.Source.ItemShop","Cosmetics.Filter.Season.4"],"showcaseVideo":"enU9gwEHRm8","displayAssetPath":null,"definitionPath":null,"path":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Cosmetics/Backpacks/BID_051_Merman","added":"2019-11-20T12:50:40Z","shopHistory":["2020-06-05T00:00:00Z","2020-07-10T00:00:00Z"]}]},{"regularPrice":2000,"finalPrice":2000,"bundle":null,"banner":{"value":"Pickaxe Included!","backendValue":"PickaxeIncluded"},"giftable":true,"refundable":true,"sortPriority":-1,"categories":["Panel 1"],"devName":"[VIRTUAL]1 x Captain America, 1 x Proto-Adamantium Shield, 1 x Proto-Adamantium Shield for 2000 MtxCurrency","offerId":"v2:/5c87c543d74ffa7b7e02058387908f5285afe87a1540c94bf9e5b2157fc0640b","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_CID_807_Athena_Commando_M_CandyApple_B1U7X","items":[{"id":"CID_807_Athena_Commando_M_CandyApple_B1U7X","name":"Captain America","description":"Super soldier Steve Rogers stands as an enduring sentinel of liberty.","type":{"value":"outfit","displayValue":"Outfit","backendValue":"AthenaCharacter"},"rarity":{"value":"marvel","displayValue":"MARVEL SERIES","backendValue":"EFortRarity::Epic"},"series":{"value":"MARVEL SERIES","image":null,"backendValue":"MarvelSeries"},"set":{"value":"Avengers","text":"Part of the Avengers set.","backendValue":"AshtonBoardwalk"},"introduction":{"chapter":"2","season":"3","text":"Introduced in Chapter 2, Season 3.","backendValue":13},"images":{"smallIcon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_807_athena_commando_m_candyapple_b1u7x/smallicon.png","icon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_807_athena_commando_m_candyapple_b1u7x/icon.png","featured":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_807_athena_commando_m_candyapple_b1u7x/featured.png","other":null},"variants":null,"gameplayTags":["Cosmetics.Source.ItemShop","Cosmetics.Filter.Season.13","Cosmetics.Set.AshtonBoardwalk"],"showcaseVideo":"p-bxqi30cGU","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_CID_807_Athena_Commando_M_CandyApple_B1U7X","definitionPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Heroes/HID_807_Athena_Commando_M_CandyApple","path":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Cosmetics/Characters/CID_807_Athena_Commando_M_CandyApple_B1U7X","added":"2020-07-03T00:00:00Z","shopHistory":["2020-07-03T00:00:00Z","2020-07-04T00:00:00Z","2020-07-05T00:00:00Z","2020-07-06T00:00:00Z","2020-07-07T00:00:00Z","2020-07-08T00:00:00Z","2020-07-09T00:00:00Z","2020-07-10T00:00:00Z"]},{"id":"BID_560_CandyApple_WTXXO","name":"Proto-Adamantium Shield","description":"Captain America's shield is as indestructible as his will.","type":{"value":"backpack","displayValue":"Back Bling","backendValue":"AthenaBackpack"},"rarity":{"value":"marvel","displayValue":"MARVEL SERIES","backendValue":"EFortRarity::Epic"},"series":{"value":"MARVEL SERIES","image":null,"backendValue":"MarvelSeries"},"set":{"value":"Avengers","text":"Part of the Avengers set.","backendValue":"AshtonBoardwalk"},"introduction":{"chapter":"2","season":"3","text":"Introduced in Chapter 2, Season 3.","backendValue":13},"images":{"smallIcon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/bid_560_candyapple_wtxxo/smallicon.png","icon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/bid_560_candyapple_wtxxo/icon.png","featured":null,"other":null},"variants":null,"gameplayTags":["Cosmetics.Source.ItemShop","Cosmetics.Filter.Season.13","Cosmetics.Set.AshtonBoardwalk"],"showcaseVideo":null,"displayAssetPath":null,"definitionPath":null,"path":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Cosmetics/Backpacks/BID_560_CandyApple_WTXXO","added":"2020-07-03T00:00:00Z","shopHistory":["2020-07-03T00:00:00Z","2020-07-04T00:00:00Z","2020-07-05T00:00:00Z","2020-07-06T00:00:00Z","2020-07-07T00:00:00Z","2020-07-08T00:00:00Z","2020-07-09T00:00:00Z","2020-07-10T00:00:00Z"]},{"id":"Pickaxe_ID_420_CandyAppleSour_JXBZA","name":"Proto-Adamantium Shield","description":"Captain America's shield is as indestructible as his will.","type":{"value":"pickaxe","displayValue":"Harvesting Tool","backendValue":"AthenaPickaxe"},"rarity":{"value":"marvel","displayValue":"MARVEL SERIES","backendValue":"EFortRarity::Epic"},"series":{"value":"MARVEL SERIES","image":null,"backendValue":"MarvelSeries"},"set":{"value":"Avengers","text":"Part of the Avengers set.","backendValue":"AshtonBoardwalk"},"introduction":{"chapter":"2","season":"3","text":"Introduced in Chapter 2, Season 3.","backendValue":13},"images":{"smallIcon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/pickaxe_id_420_candyapplesour_jxbza/smallicon.png","icon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/pickaxe_id_420_candyapplesour_jxbza/icon.png","featured":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/pickaxe_id_420_candyapplesour_jxbza/featured.png","other":null},"variants":null,"gameplayTags":["Cosmetics.Filter.Season.13","Cosmetics.Source.ItemShop","Cosmetics.Set.AshtonBoardwalk"],"showcaseVideo":null,"displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_Pickaxe_ID_420_CandyAppleSour","definitionPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Weapons/WID_Harvest_Pickaxe_CandyAppleSour","path":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Cosmetics/Pickaxes/Pickaxe_ID_420_CandyAppleSour_JXBZA","added":"2020-07-03T00:00:00Z","shopHistory":["2020-07-03T00:00:00Z","2020-07-04T00:00:00Z","2020-07-05T00:00:00Z","2020-07-06T00:00:00Z","2020-07-07T00:00:00Z","2020-07-08T00:00:00Z","2020-07-09T00:00:00Z","2020-07-10T00:00:00Z"]}]},{"regularPrice":300,"finalPrice":300,"bundle":null,"banner":{"value":"Collect the Set!","backendValue":"CollectTheSet"},"giftable":true,"refundable":true,"sortPriority":-2,"categories":["Panel 1"],"devName":"[VIRTUAL]1 x Grand Salute for 300 MtxCurrency","offerId":"v2:/6ab15fb50c05fddda89b729cdac2be0c62b51657a1aed9a6c7d0a081cb85cbed","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_EID_Fireworks","items":[{"id":"EID_Fireworks_WKX2W","name":"Grand Salute","description":"A salute to all heroes.","type":{"value":"emote","displayValue":"Emote","backendValue":"AthenaDance"},"rarity":{"value":"marvel","displayValue":"MARVEL SERIES","backendValue":"EFortRarity::Epic"},"series":{"value":"MARVEL SERIES","image":null,"backendValue":"MarvelSeries"},"set":{"value":"Avengers","text":"Part of the Avengers set.","backendValue":"AshtonBoardwalk"},"introduction":{"chapter":"2","season":"3","text":"Introduced in Chapter 2, Season 3.","backendValue":13},"images":{"smallIcon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/eid_fireworks_wkx2w/smallicon.png","icon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/eid_fireworks_wkx2w/icon.png","featured":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/eid_fireworks_wkx2w/featured.png","other":null},"variants":null,"gameplayTags":["Cosmetics.EmoteType.Dance","Cosmetics.Source.ItemShop","Cosmetics.Filter.Season.13","Cosmetics.Set.AshtonBoardwalk"],"showcaseVideo":"IntyXGvu98Q","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_EID_Fireworks","definitionPath":null,"path":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Cosmetics/Dances/EID_Fireworks_WKX2W","added":"2020-07-03T00:00:00Z","shopHistory":["2020-07-03T00:00:00Z","2020-07-04T00:00:00Z","2020-07-05T00:00:00Z","2020-07-06T00:00:00Z","2020-07-07T00:00:00Z","2020-07-08T00:00:00Z","2020-07-09T00:00:00Z","2020-07-10T00:00:00Z"]}]},{"regularPrice":1200,"finalPrice":1200,"bundle":null,"banner":null,"giftable":true,"refundable":true,"sortPriority":-1,"categories":["Panel 1"],"devName":"[VIRTUAL]1 x Airhead for 1200 MtxCurrency","offerId":"v2:/1b0d0d420617bec2104b1bfabf1023e2fefae482dcb69855305cf690b767fbc6","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_CID_432_Athena_Commando_M_Balloonhead","items":[{"id":"CID_432_Athena_Commando_M_BalloonHead","name":"Airhead","description":"Pop into action.","type":{"value":"outfit","displayValue":"Outfit","backendValue":"AthenaCharacter"},"rarity":{"value":"rare","displayValue":"Rare","backendValue":"EFortRarity::Rare"},"series":null,"set":null,"introduction":{"chapter":"1","season":"9","text":"Introduced in Chapter 1, Season 9.","backendValue":9},"images":{"smallIcon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_432_athena_commando_m_balloonhead/smallicon.png","icon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_432_athena_commando_m_balloonhead/icon.png","featured":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_432_athena_commando_m_balloonhead/featured.png","other":null},"variants":null,"gameplayTags":["Cosmetics.Source.ItemShop","Cosmetics.Filter.Season.9"],"showcaseVideo":"ZPcLdkApjVc","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_CID_432_Athena_Commando_M_Balloonhead","definitionPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Heroes/HID_432_Athena_Commando_M_BalloonHead","path":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Cosmetics/Characters/CID_432_Athena_Commando_M_BalloonHead","added":"2019-11-20T12:49:58Z","shopHistory":["2020-06-07T00:00:00Z","2020-07-10T00:00:00Z"]}]},{"regularPrice":1200,"finalPrice":1200,"bundle":null,"banner":null,"giftable":true,"refundable":true,"sortPriority":-6,"categories":["Panel 2"],"devName":"[VIRTUAL]1 x Beach Bomber, 1 x Brite Board for 1200 MtxCurrency","offerId":"v2:/dea01128e0b6f6be9111f3af81c4570e279b060f4c489edaf8a37ce5b5e59ce2","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_CID_460_Athena_Commando_F_BriteBomberSummer","items":[{"id":"CID_460_Athena_Commando_F_BriteBomberSummer","name":"Beach Bomber","description":"Make the beach party brite!","type":{"value":"outfit","displayValue":"Outfit","backendValue":"AthenaCharacter"},"rarity":{"value":"rare","displayValue":"Rare","backendValue":"EFortRarity::Rare"},"series":null,"set":{"value":"Sunshine And Rainbows","text":"Part of the Sunshine And Rainbows set.","backendValue":"SunshineAndRainbows"},"introduction":{"chapter":"1","season":"9","text":"Introduced in Chapter 1, Season 9.","backendValue":9},"images":{"smallIcon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_460_athena_commando_f_britebombersummer/smallicon.png","icon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_460_athena_commando_f_britebombersummer/icon.png","featured":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_460_athena_commando_f_britebombersummer/featured.png","other":null},"variants":null,"gameplayTags":["Cosmetics.Source.ItemShop","Cosmetics.Set.SunshineAndRainbows","Cosmetics.Filter.Season.9"],"showcaseVideo":"G8nuKcFVMHE","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_CID_460_Athena_Commando_F_BriteBomberSummer","definitionPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Heroes/HID_460_Athena_Commando_F_BriteBomberSummer","path":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Cosmetics/Characters/CID_460_Athena_Commando_F_BriteBomberSummer","added":"2019-11-20T12:49:55Z","shopHistory":["2019-07-07T00:00:00Z","2019-07-08T00:00:00Z","2019-07-13T00:00:00Z","2019-08-18T00:00:00Z","2019-10-19T00:00:00Z","2020-07-08T00:00:00Z","2020-07-09T00:00:00Z","2020-07-10T00:00:00Z"]},{"id":"BID_299_BriteBomberSummer","name":"Brite Board","description":"Shred the sunshine.","type":{"value":"backpack","displayValue":"Back Bling","backendValue":"AthenaBackpack"},"rarity":{"value":"rare","displayValue":"Rare","backendValue":"EFortRarity::Rare"},"series":null,"set":{"value":"Sunshine And Rainbows","text":"Part of the Sunshine And Rainbows set.","backendValue":"SunshineAndRainbows"},"introduction":{"chapter":"1","season":"9","text":"Introduced in Chapter 1, Season 9.","backendValue":9},"images":{"smallIcon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/bid_299_britebombersummer/smallicon.png","icon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/bid_299_britebombersummer/icon.png","featured":null,"other":null},"variants":null,"gameplayTags":["Cosmetics.Source.ItemShop","Cosmetics.Set.SunshineAndRainbows","Cosmetics.Filter.Season.9"],"showcaseVideo":null,"displayAssetPath":null,"definitionPath":null,"path":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Cosmetics/Backpacks/BID_299_BriteBomberSummer","added":"2019-11-20T12:50:33Z","shopHistory":["2020-07-08T00:00:00Z","2020-07-09T00:00:00Z","2020-07-10T00:00:00Z"]}]},{"regularPrice":1200,"finalPrice":1200,"bundle":null,"banner":null,"giftable":true,"refundable":true,"sortPriority":-6,"categories":["Panel 2"],"devName":"[VIRTUAL]1 x Cryptic , 1 x Spectral Spine for 1200 MtxCurrency","offerId":"v2:/56c1d1e0bbda67ac75d7a1df8e2ec9d5b0853c1a55b71e0c2dfa15b890bc9e17","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_CID_413_Athena_Commando_M_StreetDemon","items":[{"id":"CID_413_Athena_Commando_M_StreetDemon","name":"Cryptic","description":"Master of mystery.","type":{"value":"outfit","displayValue":"Outfit","backendValue":"AthenaCharacter"},"rarity":{"value":"rare","displayValue":"Rare","backendValue":"EFortRarity::Rare"},"series":null,"set":{"value":"Cryptic","text":"Part of the Cryptic set.","backendValue":"StreetDemon"},"introduction":{"chapter":"1","season":"9","text":"Introduced in Chapter 1, Season 9.","backendValue":9},"images":{"smallIcon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_413_athena_commando_m_streetdemon/smallicon.png","icon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_413_athena_commando_m_streetdemon/icon.png","featured":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_413_athena_commando_m_streetdemon/featured.png","other":null},"variants":null,"gameplayTags":["Cosmetics.Source.ItemShop","Cosmetics.Set.StreetDemon","Cosmetics.Filter.Season.9"],"showcaseVideo":"HrIc_ZMLSQw","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_CID_413_Athena_Commando_M_StreetDemon","definitionPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Heroes/HID_413_Athena_Commando_M_StreetDemon","path":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Cosmetics/Characters/CID_413_Athena_Commando_M_StreetDemon","added":"2019-11-20T12:49:59Z","shopHistory":["2019-05-10T00:00:00Z","2019-05-11T00:00:00Z","2019-06-13T00:00:00Z","2019-07-25T00:00:00Z","2019-09-01T00:00:00Z","2019-10-01T00:00:00Z","2019-11-05T00:00:00Z","2019-12-06T00:00:00Z","2019-12-18T00:00:00Z","2020-01-23T00:00:00Z","2020-03-03T00:00:00Z","2020-04-06T00:00:00Z","2020-05-08T00:00:00Z","2020-06-08T00:00:00Z","2020-07-10T00:00:00Z"]},{"id":"BID_270_StreetDemon","name":"Spectral Spine","description":"Show some backbone.","type":{"value":"backpack","displayValue":"Back Bling","backendValue":"AthenaBackpack"},"rarity":{"value":"rare","displayValue":"Rare","backendValue":"EFortRarity::Rare"},"series":null,"set":{"value":"Cryptic","text":"Part of the Cryptic set.","backendValue":"StreetDemon"},"introduction":{"chapter":"1","season":"9","text":"Introduced in Chapter 1, Season 9.","backendValue":9},"images":{"smallIcon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/bid_270_streetdemon/smallicon.png","icon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/bid_270_streetdemon/icon.png","featured":null,"other":null},"variants":null,"gameplayTags":["Cosmetics.Source.ItemShop","Cosmetics.Set.StreetDemon","Cosmetics.Filter.Season.9"],"showcaseVideo":null,"displayAssetPath":null,"definitionPath":null,"path":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Cosmetics/Backpacks/BID_270_StreetDemon","added":"2019-11-20T12:50:34Z","shopHistory":["2020-05-08T00:00:00Z","2020-06-08T00:00:00Z","2020-07-10T00:00:00Z"]}]},{"regularPrice":800,"finalPrice":800,"bundle":null,"banner":{"value":"It's Back!","backendValue":"Back"},"giftable":true,"refundable":true,"sortPriority":-12,"categories":["Panel 3"],"devName":"[VIRTUAL]1 x Director's Cut for 800 MtxCurrency","offerId":"v2:/2e6b8c14d82bf46058709bf4939af260761163c3aeda537446b09053302ff24d","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_Pickaxe_ID_054_FilmCamera","items":[{"id":"Pickaxe_ID_054_FilmCamera","name":"Director's Cut","description":"Lights, Camera, Axin'.","type":{"value":"pickaxe","displayValue":"Harvesting Tool","backendValue":"AthenaPickaxe"},"rarity":{"value":"rare","displayValue":"Rare","backendValue":"EFortRarity::Rare"},"series":null,"set":null,"introduction":{"chapter":"1","season":"4","text":"Introduced in Chapter 1, Season 4.","backendValue":4},"images":{"smallIcon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/pickaxe_id_054_filmcamera/smallicon.png","icon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/pickaxe_id_054_filmcamera/icon.png","featured":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/pickaxe_id_054_filmcamera/featured.png","other":null},"variants":null,"gameplayTags":["Cosmetics.Source.ItemShop","Cosmetics.Filter.Season.4"],"showcaseVideo":"l17J96vMojg","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_Pickaxe_ID_054_FilmCamera","definitionPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Weapons/WID_Harvest_Pickaxe_FilmCamera","path":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Cosmetics/Pickaxes/Pickaxe_ID_054_FilmCamera","added":"2019-11-20T12:50:58Z","shopHistory":["2018-05-25T00:00:00Z","2018-05-26T00:00:00Z","2018-06-28T00:00:00Z","2018-07-31T00:00:00Z","2018-09-04T00:00:00Z","2018-12-05T00:00:00Z","2020-07-10T00:00:00Z"]}]},{"regularPrice":500,"finalPrice":500,"bundle":null,"banner":{"value":"Animated!","backendValue":"Animated"},"giftable":true,"refundable":true,"sortPriority":-7,"categories":["Panel 2"],"devName":"[VIRTUAL]1 x Enigma for 500 MtxCurrency","offerId":"v2:/7f82f9fdd21bd5c32230f9c96e6381b627633b1a55b02a554fb96e08cdb8a1c2","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_Wrap_067_StreetDemon","items":[{"id":"Wrap_067_StreetDemon","name":"Enigma","description":"Show your style.","type":{"value":"wrap","displayValue":"Wrap","backendValue":"AthenaItemWrap"},"rarity":{"value":"rare","displayValue":"Rare","backendValue":"EFortRarity::Rare"},"series":null,"set":{"value":"Cryptic","text":"Part of the Cryptic set.","backendValue":"StreetDemon"},"introduction":{"chapter":"1","season":"9","text":"Introduced in Chapter 1, Season 9.","backendValue":9},"images":{"smallIcon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/wrap_067_streetdemon/smallicon.png","icon":"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/wrap_067_streetdemon/icon.png","featured":null,"other":null},"variants":null,"gameplayTags":["Cosmetics.Source.ItemShop","Cosmetics.UserFacingFlags.Wrap.Animated","Cosmetics.Set.StreetDemon","Cosmetics.Filter.Season.9"],"showcaseVideo":"KTTUAMlciWE","displayAssetPath":"FortniteGame/Content/Catalog/DisplayAssets/DA_Featured_Wrap_067_StreetDemon","definitionPath":null,"path":"FortniteGame/Content/Athena/Items/Cosmetics/ItemWraps/Wrap_067_StreetDemon","added":"2019-11-20T12:48:28Z","shopHistory":["2019-05-10T00:00:00Z","2019-05-11T00:00:00Z","2019-06-13T00:00:00Z","2019-07-25T00:00:00Z","2019-09-01T00:00:00Z","2019-10-01T00:00:00Z","2019-11-05T00:00:00Z","2019-12-06T00:00:00Z","2019-12-18T00:00:00Z","2020-01-23T00:00:00Z","2020-03-03T00:00:00Z","2020-04-06T00:00:00Z","2020-05-08T00:00:00Z","2020-06-08T00:00:00Z","2020-07-10T00:00:00Z"]}]},{"regularPrice":500,"finalPrice":500,"bundle":null,"banner":{"value":"Collect the Set!","backendValue":"CollectTheSet"},"giftable":true,"refundable":true,"sortPriority":-8,"categories":["Panel 2"],"devName":"[VIRTUAL]1 x Payload for 500

Comment: To go into a dictionary use multiple `[ ]`. Example for two levels; `data[...][...]`

Comment: First of all, welcome! If you have code snippets like this, it is easier to place them directly into your question. Then more people are willing to help you as they can copy and paste the code. Please add also your expected output do you need only some of the json key value pairs and what do you want to do with them?

Comment: Now I have 
json_names = json_data['data']['featured']['entries']['items']['name']

I get this in terminal: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" 

Did I do the levels correctly, and are how do I go about fixing this Type Error?

Comment: @IcedChai Somewhere in the JSON there is an array/list. Please post the full JSON as text in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be `["data"]["featured"]["entries"]` to get a list of entries.
Each entry is a dictionary, and has a key `items` where the associated value is a list of dictionaries.

For example: `response.json()["data"]["featured"]["entries"][0]["items"][1]` Would be the second item of the first entry.

```
import requests


url = "https://fortnite-api.com/v2/shop/br/combined"

response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

entries = response.json()["data"]["featured"]["entries"]

for entry in entries:
    for item in entry["items"]:
        print(item)
    print()
```